# HTTPoison ArgumentError on Phoenix mix task

Tags: elixir, httprequest, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, httpoison

I have mix task `mix fetch.btc` on phoenix app (lib/mix/tasks/fetch.btc.ex):

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Fetch.Btc do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_args) do
    res = HTTPoison.get!("https://blockchain.info/ticker")
    IO.inspect(res)
  end
end
```

When I run `mix fetch.btc` I got error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup_element(:hackney_config, :mod_metrics, 2)
    PROJ_DIR/deps/hackney/src/hackney_metrics.erl:27: :hackney_metrics.get_engine/0
    PROJ_DIR/deps/hackney/src/hackney_connect.erl:78: :hackney_connect.create_connection/5
    PROJ_DIR/deps/hackney/src/hackney_connect.erl:47: :hackney_connect.connect/5
    PROJ_DIR/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:330: :hackney.request/5
    lib/httpoison/base.ex:787: HTTPoison.Base.request/6
    lib/httpoison.ex:128: HTTPoison.request!/5
    lib/mix/tasks/fetch.btc.ex:14: Mix.Tasks.Fetch.Btc.run/1
    (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:331: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:79: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
```

But in my controller this code `res = HTTPoison.get!("https://blockchain.info/ticker")` is work success!

Info:

```
hackney: 1.15.1
httpoison: 1.5.0
phoenix: 1.4.3
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is right way make http request in mix task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in you controller runs when *the application and all it’s dependencies* are already started. `mix` tasks are run within `:mix` application which obviously does not start `:hackney` by default.

All you need is to ensure it’s started / start it manually:

```rb
def run(_args) do
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ THIS ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  Application.ensure_all_started(:hackney)
  # ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑ THIS ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑

  res = HTTPoison.get!("https://blockchain.info/ticker")
  IO.inspect(res)
end
```

Comment: thanks for you help! It's works! Where I can read more info about this for more understand?

Comment: About OTP, supervision trees and how erlang virtual machine works? There are tons of resources all around the internets. I hesitate to suggest somewhat special, check the official list http://erlang.org/faq/obtaining.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `HTTPoison.start()` before the actual call. That will also work, if you dont want to start the hackney application every time in mix file or if you do not want to start using Application.

Comment: what is realy happens when we call `HTTPoison.start()` ?

Comment: `HTTPoison` is OSS, for God’s sake. https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/blob/master/lib/httpoison/base.ex#L216

Comment: @ZubairNabi incorrect. Check the link I posted above: it starts not only required `:hackney` application, but the whole zoo. including `:httpoison` itself and all its dependencies. Well, dependencies are [`:hackney` only](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/blob/master/mix.exs#L41), but still.

Comment: it actually does what @AlekseiMatiushkin did. Starts the Httpoison application and its dependencies.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin got it. yea, `Httpoison.start` starts all the application, however for the users specific problem he can start just 'hackney'. Thanks :+1

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the file `/test/test_helper.exs`

```
# /test/test_helper.exs
ExUnit.start()
HTTPoison.start() # YOUR CODE HERE
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(SocialNetworks.Repo, :manual)
```